# A javascript library with image manipulation AND zoom functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

General question - so apologies.

I need to enhance and image client side (brightness and contrast), and allow zooming on mouse over.

For the image brightness/contrast I used Camanjs - which works well, however I can't find a way to add zooming to the canvas object (everything I try seems to revert to the original unmodified image - also it would never be as good as a 3rd party library). I see other libraries out there that do zoom - however nothing that does both zoom and brightness etc.

Does anyone know of anything (I have been googling for days).

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Hard to imagine you've been `googling for days` but didn't try MagicZoom out. No affiliation with it what so ever, but when I had to find a 3rd party plugin they were like the first ones I found from my first google search.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **update** command in the [Magic Zoom API](https://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoom/integration/#api):

```
MagicZoom.update(node,  large-image-url,  small-image-url)
```

Each time the brightness/contrast is changed in CamanJS, trigger the MagicZoom.update to fetch the local URL of the new image.

Disclaimer: We are the creators of Magic Zoom.

Comment: You should probably add a disclaimer, you work for MagicZoom. But I've used it before and it's great. This is the answer.

Comment: I second adding a disclaimer

Comment: Disclaimer now added. Sorry that was forgotten and thanks to @jdmdevdotnet and KScandrett for the reminder.